# SQL Query without any joins

Tags: where-clause

Following tables:

```
ReviewPicture(rid, pid)
ArticlePicture(aid, pid)
Picture(pid, filename)
```

I want to get the ID's of pictures which are neither used in `ArticlePicture` nor in `ReviewPicture` without using joins.

That is what i got so far - unfortunately i get every picture in `Picture`:

```
select distinct Picture.pid
FROM Picture, ReviewPicture, ArticlePicture
where Picture.pid <> ReviewPicture.pid
AND Picture.pid <> ArticlePicture.pid;
```

Comment: you are using join :)

Comment: Would you have a solution without any joins? :)

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data.  Most likely, the answer your teacher wants you to find involves using correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT Picture.pid FROM Picture
WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM ReviewPicture) AND PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM ArticlePicture)
```